# What kind of database is best with conditionals?

Tags: performance, database-design

I'm looking for the "best" (I know there is probably never an objective best anything) database-kind for chaining conditionals. To use the popular "person" analogy:

I have several characteristics that should all be applied, but it is not known whether all are set.

- haircolor
- ZIP-Code
- brother's name
- cat-Owner

A person may have all characteristics filled in or none at all. Assuming the following dataset:

```
ID:    tobias
color: blonde
cat:   false

ID:    james
cat:   true
zip:   09648

ID:    linda
bro:   john
cat:   false
zip:   01558
color: brown

ID:    ellie
cat:   true

ID:    alice
```

Querying cat-owners should give `ellie, james`

Querying brown-haired non-cat-owners should give `linda`

Data-Set estimation would be 500.000+ entries. With few writes and way more reads.

I thought Graph DBs might be a good idea at first and by making edges the various conditions I could maybe filter the entries relatively easy. Relational Databases would be easy to implement, but my goal is maximum performance so I'm not too sure about that.

Comment: How many attributes total?  50? 100? 1000?

Comment: This is what we call open-ended. It really depends on about umpteen factors as to which is best. I could write a good analysis tool for this with XML and C#, I can do it in javascript and some json files, I could do some TSQL stored procedures with adequate indexes ... and I'm just a .NET guy. There's too many questions that have to be answered to figure out "what's the best product for X". Unfortunately there's no guidelines. Are you looking to do all the work _in_ the database engine? What front-end language does the store work against? You definitely need a data architect for this.

Comment: @bbaird 10-20 attributes total

Comment: @jcolebrand Thanks, I will try to get me some help on this.